# displaying member in dictionary based on key (comboBox)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, combobox

I have a couple of different dictionary-structures that i want to display in a comboBox.

**In JumpType.cs:**

```
 public SortedDictionary<int, List<string>> jumpCombination = new SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

The dictionary structure will look something like this:

```
Key    Values
1      Flygande
       EjFlygande
2      Bak
       Pik
       Test
3      ...
```

I have created two comboBoxes in my UI like this:

```
Select Key:      _____________
                |   ComboBox  |
                --------------      __________
                 _____________      |   OK   |
Select Value:   |   ComboBox  |     ----------
                --------------
```

**In  Form1.cs**

```
 InitializeComponent();
 JumpType jt = new JumpType();
 jt.addjumpCombination(); // populating the dictionary
 if (jt.jumpCombination != null)
 {
            comboBoxJumpComboKey.DataSource = new BindingSource(jt.jumpCombination, null); // Key => null
            comboBoxJumpComboKey.DisplayMember = "Value";
            comboBoxJumpComboKey.ValueMember = "Key";
            comboBoxJumpComboValue.DisplayMember = "Value";
            var selectedValues = jt.jumpCombination //here i'm trying to access value
                    .Where(j => j.Key == Convert.ToInt32(comboJumpComboKey.SelectedItem.Value))
                    .Select(a => a.Value)
                    .ToList();
 }
```

How would i go about to select the corresponding values according to the selected key?

Thanks in advance. 
As you can see in the image, the key is displayed (1), but i cannot select anything from the combobox below it.
 [image: comboBox]

Comment: What you want to do is changing the list of the second comboBox whenever the index of the first one is changed. So you can add an event handler for `comboBoxJumpComboKey` index changed event. In that event you change the `DataSource` of `comboBoxJumpComboValue`

Comment: @Everyone yeah exactly. I don't really know how to go about doing that. Would you mind giving me a helping hand here?

Comment: You are using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms. @Everyone

Comment: I'll work on a solution.. a moment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would initialize the `Dictionary` as part of the UI class itself.

```
 public SortedDictionary<int, List<string>> jumpCombination;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        jumpCombination = new SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
        // do whatever needed to populate the dictionary here
        // now add the DataSource as the Keys of your dictionary which are integers
        comboBoxJumpComboKey.DataSource = new BindingSource(jumpCombination.Keys, null);
    }
```

Then, double click on your `comboBoxJumpComboKey` in your UI designer, a new method would come, fill it with this:

```
private void comboBoxJumpComboKey_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        comboBoxJumpComboValue.DataSource = jumpCombination[int.Parse(comboBoxJumpComboKey.Items[comboBoxJumpComboKey.SelectedIndex].ToString())];
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting "invalidArgument=Value of -1 is not valid for 'index'

Comment: Is your dictionary populated? Does it have negative numbers as keys? If you want, you could use `comboBoxJumpComboValue.DataSource = jumpCombination[comboBoxJumpComboKey.SelectedIndex];`

Comment: yes, i'm calling it after the init function. And it's getting the key as of now. But from that key-value. I want to be able to select the values that key contains (within the list)

Comment: Hmm, I tried the solution in the answer, it is working perfectly. Which one exactly is showing you the error? the `.Items[...]` or the `jumpCombination[...]` itself?

Comment: Updated question with image to illustrate the problem a bit better. With (my) current solution as in the question i get: [1, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]], so it's getting the key right, but not the values. It's just pointing to the list, and not the objects within that list.

Comment: Oh I see, try adding this `comboBoxJumpComboValue.DataSource = jumpCombination[int.Parse(comboBoxJumpComboKey.Items[comboBoxJumpComboKey.SelectedIndex].ToString())];` in the end of `public Form1(){...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135571/discussion-between-everyone-and-joel).